# jOOQ and selecting an enum field into enum object

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, enums, jooq

I'm using jOOQ with Postgresql to select an enum value from a table.

```
List<my.project.jooq.enums.Color> colors =
dsl.selectDistinct(TABLE.T_COLOR.as("color"))
   .from(TABLE).fetch()
   .into(my.project.jooq.enums.Color.class);
```

Anyway I get the exception:

```
org.jooq.exception.MappingException: No matching constructor found on type class my.project.jooq.enums.Color for record org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper@7c66447f
```

I see that `fetch()` will return `Result<Record1<my.project.model.jooq.enums.Color>>`, so I wonder if there is a way to immediately fetch the Color enums into a list as I can do with any pojo.

How can I fetch into the enum values?

Comment: Creating new enum? I don't get it. The enum are autogenerated by jOOQ. I want to fetch an enum assigned to a field of a table into the Java object autogenerated by jOOQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.7, this is not yet supported out of the box, but will be in jOOQ 3.8 (see [#5154](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5154)).

You can easily map a string column to your `Enum` type yourself, though, via

```java
List<my.project.jooq.enums.Color> colors = 
dsl.selectDistinct(TABLE.T_COLOR)
   .from(TABLE)
   .fetch()
   .map(rec -> my.project.jooq.enums.Color.valueOf(rec.getValue(TABLE.T_COLOR)));
```

In case, your `my.project.jooq.enums.Color` was generated by jOOQ from a PostgreSQL `enum` data type, you don't need to specifically map anything, jOOQ will automatically do that for you:

```java
List<my.project.jooq.enums.Color> colors = 
dsl.selectDistinct(TABLE.T_COLOR)
   .from(TABLE)
   .fetch(TABLE.T_COLOR);
```